# Two buttons in a widget

Tags: android, widget

Can someone please tell me how I can click on one button of the widget and make the view change and then on another to go to another activity?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
   First take the id of both button and store it in Btn1 and Btn2 respective id and do this
 Btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {

                public void onClick(View v){
    FrameLayout userwallFrmWall = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.floatinglist_frm_startpage);
            viewMyWall = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.mywall, null);
            userwallFrmWall.addView(viewMyWall);



    });
    Btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {

                public void onClick(View v){
    Intent intent=new Intent(this,desired.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    });
```

Comment: Use to store button id's